# Quicktime Audio Channels Assign

Tags: audio, applescript, quicktime

I have seen a couple of AppleScript script which do this, but want a better, more robust method. I have many Quicktime Prores HQ files which have a 5.1 and Stereo audio tracks wich by default are all labelled as 'mono'. You can manually open the file in quicktime pro, goto show movie properties, select an audio track, click on audio settings, and via the dropdown assign the correct label for that track, Left, right, LFE, etc. Currently I do this manually, but this is time consuming if you have a lot of files to do. Is anyone aware of anyway of doing this please without re-encoding the file, as these are just quicktime header flags. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thing I use. Its a command line application that takes a video file as an argument.

https://github.com/Pescolly/QT-Track-Mapper